# Using one Array Value As Another Array Key PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to use a value from one array as the key for another as part of a MySQL replace statement. I tried the code below but got a syntax error of

```
"Unexpected '[' expected ']'"
```

Can this be done and if so any help with the right syntax would bemuch appreciated.

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO sections(IDENTIFIER, NAME, DESCRIPTION, SEQUENCE, INSTRUCTIONS, TIME_AVAILABLE, EXTERNAL_RESOURCE)
            VALUES ('$currentline[$flippedheaders['IDENTIFIER']]', '$currentline[flippedheaders['NAME']]', '$currentline[flippedheaders['DESCRIPTION']]', $currentline[flippedheaders['SEQUENCE']], '$currentline[flippedheaders['INSTRUCTION']]', $currentline[flippedheaders['TIME_AVAILABLE']], '$currentline[flippedheaders['EXTERNAL_RESOURCE']]')";
```

Comment: What database driver are you using? Doing string interpolation is extremely error prone because you need to [properly escape all your values](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have [serious problems](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have a lot of typos there, mising quotes and not properly interpolating the string. Try as follows:

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO sections(IDENTIFIER, NAME, DESCRIPTION, SEQUENCE, INSTRUCTIONS, TIME_AVAILABLE, EXTERNAL_RESOURCE)
        VALUES ('{$currentline[$flippedheaders['IDENTIFIER']]}', '{$currentline[$flippedheaders['NAME']]}', '{$currentline[$flippedheaders['DESCRIPTION']]}', '{$currentline[$flippedheaders['SEQUENCE']]}, '{$currentline[$flippedheaders['INSTRUCTION']]}', '{$currentline[$flippedheaders['TIME_AVAILABLE']]}', '{$currentline[$flippedheaders['EXTERNAL_RESOURCE']]}')";
```

Comment: Aside from the embarrassing typos, not interpolating the string was the main issue here. I knew that's what I needed to do but not what it was called or how to do it so this was a huge help, thanks :)